Encrypt or hide password from Jenkins.xml file: --httpsKeyStorePassword
How can I hide or encrypt the SSL certificate configuration related password. Adding password in the configuration file is not recommended. We have password setup in the jenkins.xml file.
-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore="%ProgramData%\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets\jenkins-cert.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=******* --webroot="%ProgramData%\Jenkins\war"
I have tried below link, but its not working.
Unrecognized option: --httpsCertificate=/opt/certs/project.crt in Jenkins Systemd

There's no point in encrypting or otherwise hiding the password needed to decrypt the keystore because the system needs to be able to get that password to load the keystore anyway.  So you'd have to supply the system with the means to recover the password.  So anyone else could, too.
